# Access values in dict in tf.dataset.Dataset.map with tf.striing

Tags: tensorflow, tf.data.dataset

I am creating a `tf.data.Dataset` where I start with `list_files` to get all paths to my images. The annotations are stored on disc as json files. The structure of the json file is

```
{ 
   "img1.png": {
                data ...
               },
   "img2.png": ...
}
```

Hence the key-value is the image name.

I can easily extract the image names from the paths provided by `list_files`. However, that is `tf.string`, which cannot be used directly(?) to access the values in the annotation.

Is there an easy way to convert the `tf.string` to a python string so I can read the groundtruth data from the json file?

Alternatively convert the annotation to a proper `tf type`.

```
from typing import Mapping
from numpy import ndarray
import tensorflow as tf
import cv2 as cv
from pathlib import Path
from typing import Any, Mapping, NamedTuple
import json

class Point:
    x: float
    y: float

    def __init__(self, x: float, y: float):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

class BoundingBox(NamedTuple):
    top: float
    left: float
    bottom: float
    right: float

class Annotation:
    image: tf.Tensor
    bounding_box: tf.Tensor
    is_visible: bool

    def __init__(self, image, bounding_box, is_visible):
        self.image = image
        self.bounding_box = bounding_box
        self.is_visible = is_visible

LABELS = {
    "NO_CLUB": 0,
    "CLUB": 1,
    "bbox": BoundingBox,
}


def is_in_split(image_path: tf.string, is_training: bool) -> bool:
    hash = tf.strings.to_hash_bucket_fast(image_path, 10)
    if is_training:
        return hash < 8
    else:
        return hash >= 8


def create_image_and_annotation(image_path: tf.string, annotation: Mapping[str, Any]):
    bits = tf.io.read_file(image_path)
    file_split = tf.strings.split(image_path, "/")
    image_name = file_split[-1]
    suffix = tf.strings.split(image_name, ".")[-1]

    jpeg = [
        tf.convert_to_tensor("jpg", dtype=tf.string),
        tf.convert_to_tensor("JPG", dtype=tf.string),
        tf.convert_to_tensor("jpeg", dtype=tf.string),
        tf.convert_to_tensor("JPEG", dtype=tf.string),
    ]
    is_jpeg = [tf.math.equal(suffix, s) for s in jpeg]
    png = [
        tf.convert_to_tensor("png", dtype=tf.string),
        tf.convert_to_tensor("PNG", dtype=tf.string),
    ]
    is_png = [tf.math.equal(suffix, s) for s in png]
    if tf.math.reduce_any(is_jpeg):
        image = tf.io.decode_jpeg(bits, channels=3)
    else:
        image = tf.io.decode_png(bits, channels=3)
    # Here I want to use image_name to access the annotation for the specific image! <---
    bounding_box = BoundingBox(0,0,10,10)
    return image, (bounding_box, True)


def createDataset(dir: Path, annotation: Mapping[str, Any], is_training: bool) -> tf.data.Dataset:
    image_path_png = str(dir / "images" / "*.png")
    image_path_PNG = str(dir / "images" / "*.PNG")
    image_path_jpg = str(dir / "images" / "*.jpg")
    image_path_JPG = str(dir / "images" / "*.JPG")
    image_path_jpeg = str(dir / "images" / "*.jpeg")
    image_path_JPEG = str(dir / "images" / "*.JPEG")
    image_dirs = [image_path_png, image_path_PNG, image_path_jpg, image_path_JPG, image_path_jpeg, image_path_JPEG]

    dataset = (tf.data.Dataset.list_files(image_dirs)
        .shuffle(1000)
        .map(lambda x: create_image_and_annotation(x, annotation))
        )

    for d in dataset:
        pass

    return dataset

def getDataset(data_root_path: Path, is_training: bool) -> tf.data.Dataset:
        dirs = [x for x in data_root_path.iterdir() if x.is_dir()]
        datasets = []
        for dir in dirs:
            json_path = dir / "annotations.json"
            with open(json_path) as json_file:
                annotation = json.load(json_file)
                createDataset(dir, annotation, is_training=is_training)



training_data = getDataset(Path("/home/erik/Datasets/ClubHeadDetection"), True)
```

Comment: `tensor.numpy()` coverts tensor of any dtype to python dtype.

Comment: No I get: `AttributeError: 'Tensor' object has no attribute 'numpy'`

Comment: set - tf.compat.v1.enable_eager_execution()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest solution was to read the file using

```
annotation = tf.io.read_file(str(json_path))
```

Then the bounding box is created by calling

```
bbox = tf.py_function(
        create_bbox,
        inp=[annotation, image_name],
        Tout=[tf.float32, tf.float32, tf.float32, tf.float32, tf.float32],
    )
```

Inside `create_bbox` we can now call python functions. Such as

```
annotation_py = annotation.numpy()
annotation_json = json.loads(annotation_py)
key_py = image_name.numpy().decode("utf-8")
```

Answer (score 0):

It is possible when converting the feature name from string to int or you added a ragged tensor into it. You can map labels and data from the phase method. [Train example](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/train/Example)

Sample: Same as mapping using dataset.map function but it specifically to convert to int or you can use a ragged tensor for < data, label >

```
import os
from os.path import exists

import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_io as tfio
from google.protobuf import json_format

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
[PhysicalDevice(name='/physical_device:GPU:0', device_type='GPU')]
None
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
physical_devices = tf.config.experimental.list_physical_devices('GPU')
assert len(physical_devices) > 0, "Not enough GPU hardware devices available"
config = tf.config.experimental.set_memory_growth(physical_devices[0], True)
print(physical_devices)
print(config)

"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
: Variables
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""           
image = tf.io.read_file( "F:\\Pictures\\Kids\\images.jpg" )
image = tf.io.decode_jpeg(image)                            
image = tf.cast( image, dtype=tf.int64 )
                    
example = tf.train.Example(
    features=tf.train.Features(
        feature={
            "1": tf.train.Feature(
            
                int64_list=tf.train.Int64List(
                    value=tf.constant( image, shape=( 183 * 275 * 3 ) ).numpy() )
                    
                    ),
            "2": tf.train.Feature(
            
                int64_list=tf.train.Int64List(
                    value=tf.constant( image, shape=( 183 * 275 * 3 ) ).numpy() )
                    
                    )       
            }))

data_string = json_format.MessageToJson(example)
example_binary = tf.io.decode_json_example(data_string)

example_phase = tf.io.parse_example(
    serialized=[example_binary.numpy()],
    features = {    "1": tf.io.FixedLenFeature(shape=[ 183 * 275 * 3 ], dtype=tf.int64),
                    "2": tf.io.FixedLenFeature(shape=[ 183 * 275 * 3 ], dtype=tf.int64)
                })

data = list(example_phase.items())
label = [ int(x[0]) for x in data ]

data = [ x[1] for x in data ]
data = [ x[0] for x in data ]

dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensors(( data, label ))

# for d in dataset:
    # print( d )

plt.imshow( tf.constant( example_phase['1'], shape=( 183, 275, 3) ) )
plt.show()
```

Output:

```
(<tf.Tensor: shape=(2, 150975), dtype=int64, numpy=
array([[227, 162, 132, ..., 227, 169, 129],
       [227, 162, 132, ..., 227, 169, 129]], dtype=int64)>, <tf.Tensor: shape=(2,), dtype=int32, numpy=array([1, 2])>)
```

[Input used](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vH6zM.png)